# Sum of contiguous subarrays of an array in least time

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
long sum(int[] arr) {
    long sum=0;
    int j,k;
    long sumtoadd;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            sumtoadd = 0;
            for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
            {
                sumtoadd = sumtoadd + arr[k];
            }
            sum = sumtoadd + sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Example:

> Array : {1,2,3} Output: 20
>
> Array : {1,1,1} Output: 10

I am trying to find the sum of all contiguous subarrays of an array, but for some of the cases, time is exceeding. **This solution is working for all cases except large sized cases.** Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Please post input and expected output

Comment: Don't reset the counter. You're adding up the same items over and over again. Think about what you are adding up - `n * arr[n-1]`, `(n-1) * arr[n-2]` etc.

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test1 {

static long sum2(int[] arr) {
    long n = arr.length;
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += (n-i)*(i+1)*arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

static int[] arr1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
static int[] arr2 = new int[]{1,1,1,1};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("sum(arr1) = " + sum(arr1));
    System.out.println("sum2(arr1) = " + sum2(arr1));
    System.out.println("sum(arr2) = " + sum(arr2));
    System.out.println("sum2(arr2) = " + sum2(arr2));
}

//your code to check
static long sum(int[] arr) {
    long sum=0;
    int j,k;
    long sumtoadd;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            sumtoadd = 0;
            for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
            {
                sumtoadd = sumtoadd + arr[k];
            }
            sum = sumtoadd + sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Comment: using sum2, now I'm not receiving timeout error but it is showing the answer is wrong for those large cases. I can't even see the inputs because inputs are hidden.

Comment: @NaMo: i've switch to `long n=arr.length`, could you please try again?

Comment: DONE because size of array was large and n is int. Yeah.

Comment: Array can not exceed maxint, it was because of multiplication cast to int instead of long

Answer (score 0):

Instead of three nested loops, the answer can be found in one loop over the `N` array elements.

Reasoning:

If a given array element `A[i]` occurs in `K` subarrays, then it contributes its value to `K` subarrays, meaning it contributes `K`-times its value to the total sum. Now the element `A[i]` occurs in all subarrays with a start from `0` to `i` (inclusive), and an end from `i+1` to `N` (inclusive), so `K = (i+1)*(N-i)`.

Summary: every `A[i]` contributes `(i+1)*(N-i)*A[i]`. Do that in a single loop, and you're finished.